# how to render the data to frontend like social media

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs

How to render the data in 10 or 15 pairs to the front end. when users see all of these 10 and backend sends them again 10 pairs of posts. it's like a social media app. where they rendering the data in pairs of 10 or 15, Facebook sends data in some pairs, and when we see all of the posts and start loading and get again 10 or 15 pairs of posts. I am using nodejs, mongodb and ejs . I am not understanding how to do this.

Comment: Will you please clarify what part of this you don't understand and what you have already tried?

Comment: no, I don't know where to start. i am newr